# Remove alert.js file from magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript

I want to remove alert.js file from my DOM.
following is the file location

```
"vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\web\js\modal\alert.js"
```

I tried so many ways in my child theme's default.xml file

`<remove src="Magento_Ui::js/modal/alert.js"/>`

But it still load in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try with default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <remove src="Magento_Ui::js/modal/alert.js"/>
</head>
```

hope it will help you

Comment: I tried, but it can't work for me.

Comment: Hello,
it is happening because js called by another ko component.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Payment/view/frontend/web/js/transparent.js#L10